# PHP DOMDocument removeChild() only removing only the first instance of targeted class

Tags: php, domdocument, removechild

I need to remove all instances of a particular class (only assigned to `div`s) from an HTML document. Here's the snippet I'm using:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($meaning);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node) {
        if($node->getAttribute('class') == "someclass"){
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
    }
```

This works fine except that it only removes the first occurrence of the said class, leaving the rest behind. Is this normal behavior? What should I modify in my code to ensure all nodes attributed to this class are removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot.  The key is to use `DomNodeList::item()`, as you'll see below:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($meaning);

/** @var DomNodeList $divs */
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

for ($i = 0; $i < $divs->length; $i++) {
    /** @var DomElement $node */
    $node = $divs->item($i);
    if ($node->getAttribute('class') == 'someclass') {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        $i--; // Since we just removed an element, we need to readjust our pointer.
    }
}
```